# What's the correct notation for log squared?

Tags: notation

I ran across these two notations for the log function (squared), which one is **more** conventional.

$\log^2(n)$ or $[\log(n)]^2$

Comment: not matter of $\textbf{correct}$ it is a matter of which is more $\bf{conventional}$, and to answer it: $\log^2(n)$.

Comment: Does the same go for $ln$?

Comment: Better be clear than rely on conventions if you think you might be misunderstood.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro Yes, the same goes for $\ln^2(x)$ and $\big(\ln(x)\big)^2$.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most people will use $\log^2(n)$ and there is no problem with that. If you want to be absolutely certain no one will think you are talking about $\log\log n$, then  you can write $\bigl(\log(n)\bigr)^2$

Comment: When there is only one variable in the argument, it is common to write $\log^2n$.

Comment: How about for $ln$ (natural log), do most people use $ln^2(x)$ as well?

Comment: Grownups use $\log$ for the natural log. If you want to be absolutely certain that no one will think you are talking about common logartihms, you can use $\ln$. If for some reason you want to talk about common logs and you want to be certain no one will misunderstand, you can write $\log_{10}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "Grownups use log for the natural log."

I believe most mathematicians is a more appropriate noun.

Comment: Wow, using $\log^2(n)$ to stand for $(\log n)^2$ seems terrible.  It looks like function iteration, i.e. $\log \log n$.  How do people know what they are talking about?  Context?

Comment: @Ray, yes, context. But I think it's a bit unusual to use $\log^2n$ for $\log\log n$.

Comment: Interesting, and thank you. That bothers me no end, though.  It bothered Babbage, too, from what I understand, at least if one believes what [Wikipedians have written about Abuse of Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Trigonometric_functions).

Comment: There's a lot of notation inconsistencies. $f^2 (n)$ usually means $f(f(n))$ not $f(n)^2$, yet $\sin^2 x$ means $(\sin x)^2$. IMO it boils down to the fact that $\log \log x$ is not very commonly used, and $\sin \sin x$ (as far as I know) makes no sense to ever use since $\sin x$ puts in an angle and gives you a ratio, so you would be giving a ratio to be interpreted as an angle to give a ratio.

Comment: Well, the antiderivative of (sin x + 1), a perfectly legitimate function, I may add, is (cos x + x), which does the same sort of ratio / angle mixing... I personally find the abuse of notation annoying for even trig functions.

Comment: @MichaelT, "$\log\log x$ is not very commonly used" --- this will come as news to fans of Analytic Number Theory, who have grown accustomed to that and $\log\log\log x$, and even $\log\log\log\log x$.

Comment: is log log n same as log^2 n? Can log^2 n be simplified further?

Comment: @May, $\log\log n$ is certainly not the same as $(\log n)^2$ – just plug in any value of $n$, and see for yourself – and $(\log n)^2$ is pretty simple already.

Comment: @GerryMyerson vast majority of computer scientists consider $\log$ to be log base 2

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 well, computer scientists use logs mostly inside the O-notation, and there the base is kind of irrelevant