# Nested log notation

Tags: notation

As a complement to this question: [What's the correct notation for log squared?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124443/whats-the-correct-notation-for-log-squared) What is the correct notation for $\log (\log \log ( ...  \log((n))))$?

By analogy, with the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$, one could write $f^{(n)}(x)$ so that it can't be confused with raising $f(x)$ to the $n$th power as $f^n(x)$ could. Is there some convention like that?

Comment: a) $\log \log x$, b) explain the notation you use and write $\log^3 x$ etc. for the composition, c) $\log^{(\circ 5)} x$, d) sorry, run out of ideas.