# Differentiation of logarithm

Tags: derivatives

$$\left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x}\right)^3 = \frac{(\ln x)^3}{x^3} $$

Is $(\ln x)^3 $ same as $\ln x^3$ ?

Meaning when before I differentiate it, I can move the $3$

$$ 3 \ln x. $$

Comment: The identity $(\ln x)^3=3\ln x$ holds for **literally** three real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

No. Generally speaking, function composition is not commutative.

$$(f\circ g)(x)\ne(g\circ f)(x)$$ or

$$f(g(x))\ne g(f(x)).$$

---

$$(\ln x^3)'=(3\ln x)'=\frac3x\ne(\ln^3x)'=3\ln^2x(\ln x)'=\frac{3\ln^2 x}x.$$

Answer (score 2):

No, $$\ln(x^3)\neq(\ln(x))^3$$
in general. You would need to use the chain rule to differentiate $(\ln(x))^3$.

Comment: Also, $(\ln(x))^3$ is commonly denoted as $\ln^3x$.

Comment: @Puding It is? I've only seen that convention used commonly for the trigonometric functions, not for other functions.

Comment: @Deepak It is a very common notation, at least in theoretical computer science. Parentheses are a pain to type and parse, $(\log n)^2$ is much less convenient than $\log^2 n$.

Comment: Yes, it is mainly used with trigonometric functions, because they are much more often raised to powers than logarithm, but there is no reason why the same notation couldn't be applied to any function. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124443/whats-the-correct-notation-for-log-squared). @Deepak